# How can I encourage Stack Overflow to rein in the 'subjective' vigilantes?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, subjective

I'm on SO pretty much every day researching something to do with programming, and over the last month or two, I find I'm growing frustrated and a little disgusted at how many interesting questions have been closed as "not a good fit" or "too subjective".

I think there is a confusion between "subjective" and "calls for judgement".
To me one of the *most* valuable things about SO is the tremendous breadth and depth of experience of the members, and experience translates into smart decisions and advice, and that advice cannot always be asked for, or expressed in terms of, bald facts and data.  It's going to be 'subjective'.

I don't think SO should be Wikipedia. I think that if I could ask a question to a group of skilled programmers sitting around a table at lunch, and get interesting, valuable answers, then I don't care whether the question or the answers are 'subjective', I think that question should equally well be fair game for Stack Overflow.

I would like to see a mechanism whereby people who vote to close a question lose reputation when somebody expresses interest in that question or its responses.

How can I, or can I, influence this aspect of SO?

Comment: I'm dropping the [feature-request] tag because even though you have a sentence that asks for a rep drop under certain circumstances, I feel like the rest of your question makes for a good, constructive discussion and I'd rather focus on that first. If the outcome of this discussion *is* some sort of technical solution, it's likely best posted separately and with more details.

Comment: Your question would be aided by some examples: what do you consider a "subjective" question, vs. one that "calls for judgement"?

Comment: People can reasonably disagree--that's what makes some things subjective, even if those subjective opinions are well-informed, lucid, and relevant. IMO SO's purpose isn't to, say, discuss relative merits of two frameworks. I'm opposed to the proposed mechanism because interest in a question is subjective, and nobody should be *punished* because someone disagrees with their opinion on a question.

Comment: I don't get this.  If you use SO for research then you'll have, ballpark numbers, 3 million questions to look at are on topic and not closed and at least 2 million good answers.  If you keep running into closed ones then you are just using the wrong site to do your research.  Fix that by finding another site, not trying to change this one.

Comment: Concerning *"I would like to see a mechanism whereby people who vote to close a question lose reputation when somebody expresses interest in that question or its responses."* see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167404/ from just today (or yesterday depending on your timezone) and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9817/ from long ago.

Comment: Also related would be the blog post [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: To those of you who patiently explained and linked, thank you.
Anna especially, thanks.

Comment: Not accepting your premise but to remove 1000 insanely unhelpful questions 1 or 2 good ones may have to fall

Comment: The premise that these are "the best questions" is rather flawed. 2 of them ask for the "best X" with no criteria whatsoever, 1 shows no effort to solve the problem before asking, and the other is about meetings, which belongs on the Workplace or Programmers sites.

Comment: Define "best". Best for **what**?

Comment: Please note that closing questions is not restricted to moderators and that members having reached a certain threshold of reputation can vote to close questions. As for the reasons, they are stated and explained in each question and I don't think that they can be more clear than that.

Comment: It's really hard to not pull the deletion trigger after seeing some of those questions. "Are weekly status meetings necessary?" Seriously?

Comment: interesting != useful

Comment: just because they're old and have a lot of  upvotes doesn't make them the best questions.

Comment: How can you know that anyone’s vague "reckonings" is any more useful than your own opinion, or mine, or that guy over there’s

Comment: All I'm saying is that I found most of them very useful and informative.  I came to find the answer to a question, albeit a vague one, and they helped.   So what if it's not a definitive answer?

Comment: "So what if it's not a definitive answer?" Stack Overflow advertises itself as a site where you'll find definitive answers. Allowing questions that have extremely little - if any - chance of generating definitive answers breaks that promise. There are plenty of other places on the internet where you can get answers to overly vague and broad questions.

Comment: `I'm only interested in stuff that's useful to me` - of course you are. But we don't care **just** about **you**.

Comment: @Oded, on one of those questions, 65 people clicked on a button that says 'This answer is useful'.

Comment: Popular doesn't mean it fits.

Comment: You might want to read [A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/05/a-group-is-its-own-worst-enemy.html) and the [The Trouble With Popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/)

Comment: 4 years before some questions where allowed for increasing traffic, but not now! because the traffic already there!

Comment: @JasonOOO They weren't allowed to increase the traffic so much as it took some time for the community to realize the questions were bad for the site.  At first, the community, like so many new users, just didn't think the questions were bad/problematic.  When they began to realize how much of a problem they were to deal with, the decision was made that they shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: @Servy: but I am sure that the traffic is one of main factors that changed the direction of this community, I am not considering this as bad idea, it usual and ok for me.

Comment: @JasonOOO And what's your evidence for that assertion?  Is it just a guess?

Comment: @MattDarwin, just give up, why waste more of your time? with your final edit of the question, unfortunately, this one will be marked as duplication soon...

Comment: related: [How can Stack Overflow help developers evaluate technologies?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145807/162704)

Comment: All questions about _close votes_ are marked as a duplicate here. However I don't entirely agree with _subjective_ posts here. BUT I do think there are too many questions being closed (many good ones) and too many downvotes being freely cast at questions. I think there should really be some penalty for downvoting questions and closing questions as off-topic.

Comment: related: [Could subjective discussions be supported using another format?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216879/248463)

Comment: OP , i doubt you can do that. there might be 1000 of developers, asking for the same, but due to some "over-zealous" opinions from some developers on SO, wont leave any chance that your opinion succeeds.

Comment: I don't know if someone already said this, but your ciriticism is totally appropriate and I agree completely.  This site has a voting model -- if it's not working to weed out poor quality responses (determined by the democratic populace--not by moderators), then the VOTING MODEL needs fixed.  That is the right answer, not censorship.  BECAUSE IT IS ENTIRELY SUBJECTIVE as to what counts as a good question.  Even the long-winded diatribe on "good subjective, bad..." doesn't get the point.

Comment: Even on a seemingly subjective questions one *can* make some objective statements. E.g. "what is the best CMS" would be a horrible question for stackexchange, and I am not at all defending it here, to be clear. But "A recent study showed that most companies choose a CMS for random or irrational reasons" (I just made this up, I have no clue really) might be an objective statement that readers will find useful. I am not arguing for anything specific here, just pointing this out.

Answer (score 197):

**tl;dr**

We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out. C'est la vie.

---

In 2010, a Stack Exchange site called [Not Programming Related](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) came out of [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the Stack Exchange staging zone. NPR was supposed to be a site where questions that were too subjective / broad for Stack Overflow would find a new home. The site was greeted with enthusiasm, and in theory it looked like a perfect solution: Stack Overflow would remain as laser sharp focused as possible, and NPR would host all those exciting and sometimes helpful (but not really *answerable*) questions.

However, as it usually happens, theory and practice are two entirely different beasts. NPR's promise proved extremely attractive to people who were more interested in posting joke answers, or just repeating earlier answers, or posting outright crap ([Do you fart in the cubicle?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49548/do-you-fart-in-the-cubicle)). It didn't take long for everyone to realize that the site was not working, and most people just didn't bother with it. Here's what [Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/programmers.stackexchange.com#!traffic) tells us for the first year of NPR's existence:

[image]

Tons and tons of people visited the site after it went public, but very few decided to stick around. For over a year, the site experienced no growth to speak of. And even fewer people contributed worthwhile content. Turns out that while everyone *loves* those questions, very few are *actually* willing to spend any time to answer them (seriously), and maintain and moderate them.

Fortunately, Stack Exchange realized their mistake soon enough. First, [Joel warned us](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/merging-season/) that the site was "degrading into fairly stupid water-cooler nonsense" and then Jeff stepped in, and [*enforced* the infamous subjective guidelines](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/the-six-subjective-question-guidelines-enforcement-notice). It took more than a few months for people to realize that NPR's (by then already renamed to Programmers) scope had changed drastically. The site had been heavily advertised as [Stack Overflow's toilet bowl](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-programmers-se-as-your-toilet-bowl), and naturally most people believed it was just that, long after the subjective guidelines were enforced.

To make matters even more complicated, there was a small - but solid - group of early members that were attracted to the site by its initial scope *and* were contributing high quality content. Unfortunately, they weren't enough to maintain a healthy site, and some - if not all - of them were (understandably) quite frustrated after the drastic change. They were doing everything right, and then suddenly the site they were originally promised was no more.

Then came the clean-ups. Changing the scope wasn't enough, we had to change the way we advertised ourselves to the world. Just saying that we were now a serious Q&A site about software design wasn't going to cut it, at least not until we cleaned up all the content that no longer fit the site's scope. After a few months of intense Meta drama, we deleted about 2K questions. And then some. A couple more months passed, but finally we started experiencing growth:

[image]

Whatever your opinion of the site's current scope might be, you can't overlook the fact that it only started growing when it became a <strike>vigorously moderated</strike> serious Q&A site. Growth aside, every other aspect of the site gradually improved. Hard questions that were once ignored in favour of the latest "let's build yet another list" question are now answered, correctly and relatively fast. More and more people have Programmers as their top site, the one site that they actively and regularly contribute. We are not there yet, but we are certainly on the right track.

The site you seem to want existed for more than a few months, and it failed. Horribly. I'm sorry but I see no reason to try it again.

#### Further reading

- [What is the history behind the site scope change from NPR to “conceptual questions about software development”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3412/25936)
- [Adding discipline to programmers.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65437/162704)
- [Should Programmers.SE exist?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153082/162704)

Comment: Possibly the unimaginable-hell-hole-exchange needs to exist so we can point to it and say "see!"

Comment: Wow... I never knew all that about Programmers' history!

Comment: Isn't that what Yahoo! Answers is for @RichardTingle?

Comment: Isn't it normal for a site to grow in visitors and regular users as it ages? It seems a bit arbitrary to directly link the change in scope with visitors when so many other factors play a role in how a site gains users, especially since if you [graph user activity (votes) on Data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/66286#graph) there is a steady decline. Or see my answer [here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3136/are-we-going-down-hill/3140#3140) for more details/stats/graphs regarding user retention

Comment: Voting is just one aspect of user activity @Rachel, and if you look closely at your graph only the upvotes are in steady decline. Given that Programmers was plagued with bs upvotes early on (polls and fun questions tend to get extremely upvoted), that's actually a good thing.

Comment: @Yannis, I was wondering if the problem could not have been on embracing subjective questions, but rather on the method for doing so (opening a whole SE site and with a naming that appealed for non-programming questions)? Has it been considered just to treat subjective questions differently in SO, like not giving reputation or other? Some questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012573/getting-started-with-haskell still seem so useful. It is a pity to see them closed

Comment: This too was tried, @Thomas: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61526/

Comment: Yes but Programmers was intended to be questions related to programming but off-topic at StackOverflow.com like "recommend me a book". Now they are Off-Topic there too.

Comment: To say that something is impossible to achieve is almost always incorrect. The attempts at having a website for subjective programming related questions that uses the stack exchange engine/format may have failed, but that does not mean it cannot work. We just need to keep brainstorming and trying different things. When something does not work, you should ask yourself how you can do it differently to make it work, not give up.

Comment: I think something like elite.programmers.stackexchange.com has a decent chance of working if it required you to have a certain amount of points on SO or programmers before you can participate. Or perhaps subjective or otherwise against the rule programming related questions should be allowed by people with a certain number of points, but only people with over a certain number of points are aloud to respond to them or comment about them. Part of the reason people want a site like this is just because of the format Stack Exchange websites have, which tends to be much better than other websites.

Comment: How does a site with a misleading name like "Not Programming Related" count as trying this _development_ related concept?  "Not Programming Related" to most people means OFF TOPIC.  And you all were "shocked" when this resulted in a ton of off topic crap?  Gee, I never would have seen that one coming.

Comment: NPR was a SE site @Crusader. It had a FAQ, an on topic and an off topic list, there was a lot more to it than just the name. And its main problem wasn't the crap questions, it was that the _on topic_ questions weren't working.

Comment: Not sure it really matters. The name was misleading. You'll never attract serious visitors with a name like that. People that want this type of site are looking for a specific type of public forum, and "Not Programming Related" is not even close to conveying the purpose. Don't you think it would be a little hard to attract people looking for serious (but subjective) interaction if many potential serious participants (myself including) *never even looked at the site because they assumed it was off topic based on the name?* Now, if you can prove the name didn't poison the well, that's different.

Comment: I don't understand where this obsession over "growth" has come form? Who cares if the site isn't "growing"? Maybe the number of users has saturated - everyone from SO who wanted to use it by a certain time are already using it...? I do agree - what's the point of having a site full of what is basically garbage nonsense, but for more subjective questions? This could have been useful and is something we need.

Comment: This is ridiculous.   Just fix your voting model to allow "big up" and "big down" votes, like I mentioned elsewhere on SE.  You can incorporate reputation by weighting such votes by a factor equal to USER_REP/SUM_OF_ALL_USER_REP.

Comment: @Marxos you know what is _really_ ridiculous is your totally unsubstantiated desire to twist and break approach that has been proven to work well for many years for over hundred question and answer sites for... what? for making it serve a need that has been already addressed perfectly well by myriads of internet forums. When I need opinions and discussion, I go to forums and have it done perfectly well, and when I need answer to a question I go to [real Q&A](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) site and I don't have any need to mix these, simple as that

Comment: @gnat:  1) it is not unsubstantiated.  I'm a media-studies researcher.  I've assembled the history of these problems and different solutions of "massive community participation".  2) Everything in the world is an opinion at some level.  Your hair color could have 5 different answers.  Study Epistemology and Metaphysics, and then come back.

Comment: And today it's called Software Engineering

Comment: So what is the best place to "discuss" in Q&A form subjective but good questions?  Any ideas?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski: a non-SE site such as [HackerNews](https://news.ycombinator.com) (superb), Quora, Medium, Twitter, Reddit or any of the many language-specific blogs, or the -devel mailing-list of a specific language/package. In all sincerity this is itself a good question for Meta, but a minority of people would nark about subjectivity.

Answer (score 57):

> I think that if I could ask a question to a group of skilled programmers sitting **around a table at lunch**, and get interesting, valuable answers, then I don't care whether the question or the answers are 'subjective', I think that question should equally well be fair game for Stack Overflow...

Assuming it's like group sitting around "table at lunch" is exactly where you are mistaken.

To find out why, consider studying Shirky's article **[A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy](https://web.archive.org/web/20191122004739/http://www.shirky.com/writings/group_enemy.html)**. The article is fantastic, it could profoundly teach the reader about the difference between a lunch group and large community, but for the sake of brevity I'll just quote the key point relevant to the mistake in your assumption:

## "human interaction... doesn't blow up like a balloon"

---

Simply put, when there's a [handful of colleagues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) in a group, a subjective conversation can go like this: first person asks a question, second answers it, third one answers from a different perspective, fourth sparks a joke, fifth adds a side note... and that's all.

- In a setting like this, you get a *reasonably limited* amount of information, an amount your brain can handle... you've got something you can *learn* from.
  [image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Dining_philosophers.png/200px-Dining_philosophers.png]

At Stack Overflow, you better think of something like **1000** people sitting around the... world.

In such an environment, your subjective conversation will probably go like this: first person asks a (subjective) question, second answers it (so far so good huh?), **twenty** more add answers from different perspectives, **fifty** more attempt all imaginable kinds of jokes, **hundred** more add all imaginable kinds of side notes... and so on and so on, over and over again, until your brain explodes.

- Trying to *learn* anything from this would be like [drinking from a firehose](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drink_from_a_firehose)
   
  [image: http://kennysilva.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/firehose.jpg]

Comment: Wow, that "A Group is Its Own Worst Enemy" article is excellent, I can't thank you enough.  One note - some supposedly 'subjective' conversations (on SO) go that way, but some don't, it's not a law.  I understand though; To avoid drowning in bathwater, we have to throw out a few babies.

Comment: @Spike0xff these thanks would better go to MichaelT: his rather heavy promotion of this article [at Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7633469#7633469 "Programmers chat") made me curious enough to invest efforts into studying it. I think you got it right with the reasoning about avoiding "drowning in bathwater"

Comment: "The best way to learn something is when someone else figures it out and tells you: "Don't go in that swamp. There are alligators in there." Learning from experience about the alligators is lousy, compared to learning from reading, say." Beautifully put, Thanks for the article.

Comment: I can understand the perspective you're articulating; however, there's a problem waiting to be solved here.  People want to ask subjective questions even if there are many perspectives and side notes.  I can understand also that SO doesn't support this kind of things; however, that doesn't mean there isn't some implementation that could somewhat overcome the issues you describe.

Comment: @Mario right. The very article I am referring to ("A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy"), describes an example of such an implementation (MetaFilter)

Comment: I drink so much answer just for this question

Comment: So to prove this, have you read enough of these answers to explode your brain?  Pointing to that article as proof in itself would be an Appeal to Authority logical fallacy.  The fire hydrant pic was hilarious, but I don't buy your argument here that there is *zero* value in being able to scan through as many viewpoints as you want.  Just yet another theoretical/subjective opinion.  I find reading subjective Q&A valuable, at times.  (On a side note, I bet that guy was able to drink as much water as he wanted!)

Comment: it's not just theory. ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: ...somewhat funny to see comment about how easy it would be to handle questions with multiple answers from someone who seems to have missed a top answer in this very question (which incidentally describes what happened when we tried to support such questions)

Comment: @Crusader - gnat has read enough to explode *anyones* brain, it's a wonder he can still function.  The article citation wasn't an appeal to authority, it was a reference to an argument that is intended to be persuasive on merit.  Subjective QA *can* be valuable, but it has proven hard not to have it degenerate to the lowest common denominator and drive away the knowledgeable.  Which is quite unfortunate, as subjective QA can help solve a much broader set of problems.

Comment: @gnat I disagree with the answer. It's *very* plausible, unless you can prove otherwise, that the title "Not Programming Related" simply made serious participants avoid even looking at the site. It's just a verbose way of saying "Off Topic". Personally I know I never even noticed it. If I avoided it for that reason, how many others also did? **I think the name of this alleged "trial" of this concept poisoned the well.** So basically I don't accept the premise of the argument here that "this was tried before". If this was the intent with NPR, it was a piss poor attempt... you have to see that.

Comment: I'm not sure why I even bother... it'll never be attempted again due to the rigid opinions (and quite possibly egos) of those in control around here, and that's that. For all I know the site was intentionally given such a terrible name (i.e. basically "Off Topic") so it would be doomed to fail and could be used as a "told you so" example against the people here clamoring for a subjective question site. I would hope nobody would be that petty, but developers seem to be known for their easily bruised egos after all. Funny firehose pic though.

Comment: That article is phenomenal. I'm sad I've never read it before today!

Comment: I think this has to be the funniest thing I have ever seen on Meta. You said, "human interaction... doesn't blow up like a balloon" - unless it is a water-balloon, connected to a firehose! Haw Haw. Seriously, I see more Answers and Comments on Meta than anywhere else. And basically, any question is fair game, and the downvotes can go in to the triple digits. I think META is really what people want: Interaction is King!!! Meta is Reality IT, it should have been created first, then most of the problems of the main sites would never have happened.

Comment: The idea of being "flooded with opinions" is a poor answer at best and mostly bullshit.  It takes time to make answers, most people who could answer WON'T. 1) because they won't find the questions amidst the millions of quesitons :) 2) if they do find the question, they aren't that interest in it, 3) if they are interested in it, it takes time to write a response, and 4) they have to write a response AND have the reputation associated with it.  That's four filters right there and why there aren't thousands of answers on every question.

Comment: nice theory @Marxos and compelling assumptions. Guess Atwood thought about the same when he initially allowed such questions at Stack Overflow. Now ask yourself how come than few years later he forbid these and off-loaded them to separate site. Ask yourself, who in their sane mind would get rid of popular and entertaining content if it's as harmless and "filtered" as you seem to believe. Then take a look at Atwood's article [The Trouble With Popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/), specifically part where he mentions "The stuff spreads like kudzu..."

Comment: @gnat:  these problems have been experimented on since Slashdot started some serious work back in the 90s.  The problem is simply that the voting model isn't adequate.  Slashdot has the same problem, but don't ban users for the inadequacies of the voting model.

Comment: The link leads to viagra advertisment. Unfortunately I couldn't find an alternative source. Anyone else?

Answer (score 26):

> I think that if I could ask a question to a group of skilled programmers sitting around a table at lunch, and get interesting, valuable answers, then I don't care whether the question or the answers are 'subjective',

That's fine. *We* care.

We care because subjective discussions will destroy this site. We care because subjective discussion is exactly why many of us are on this site instead of on many of the thousands of programming forums on the Internet.

Stack Overflow is not intended to be everything for everyone. You come here to ask objective, practical questions that have real, objective answers. If you want to have a subjective discussion about some programming issue, that's wonderful.

Don't do it *here* just because there happen to be a lot of smart people here. You'd be subverting the very reason why those smart people are here.

What you're asking is no different from wanting to read a book at a movie theater; what you want is at odds with why the place exists.

> I would like to see a mechanism whereby people who vote to close a question lose reputation when somebody expresses interest in that question or its responses.

This is one of the most ridiculous suggestions I've ever seen someone seriously suggest for this site. The potential for abuse of this is so massive that nobody would ever close anything *again*.

> How can I, or can I, influence this aspect of SO?

This is one of the *founding* aspects of SO. You can no more influence this than a fish can change the flow of the river. The anti-subjective bias is not merely part of the community, it is at the very core of why Stack Overflow *was invented*.

Again, it's like being annoyed that movie patrons ask you to turn off your reading light at the theater. You're not going to get them to change their views either.

SO is lenient in some respects to different opinions. This is not one of those cases.

Comment: "This is one of the most ridiculous suggestions I've ever seen someone seriously suggest for this site."OK, I get it, I misunderstood SO.

Comment: Ironically, I picked this as the best answer, although @gnat - thanks, very informative.  The hostility underlying this answer puzzles me though, and it exemplifies why, for me, SO increasingly feels like a bad neighborhood.  I go there when I need something, but I'm not going to hang around any longer than I have to.  Yes, I know, that just proves I'm not the right kind of people.

Comment: I consider myself to be a reasonably intelligent person but yet I can't ask an intelligent question which even has a small element of subjectivity to it because it will get _hostility_ and _downvoted_ and _delete requests_ until it's _removed and I still didn't get anywhere._ What's the deal with that? Why the extreme intolerance for a question which contains even a small amount of subjectivity? If you read the guidelines it says "of topic because primarily opinion based" - _primarily_ being the keyword there.

Comment: If avoiding discussions is not appropriate for this site, then change it into a question and answer site with a voting system to weed out poor answers.

Answer (score 20):

So far the only site that I've ever been on or heard of that removed questions such as those is the SE network, so to answer your question of:

> Where should this information be exchanged if it's not on stackoverflow?

Literally *anywhere* else on the entire internet.  Any forum, q/a site, or interactive site that allows one to ask programming questions.  Virtually none of them will refuse to allow questions like this.  There are lots and lots of places where people can go to ask these questions.

You might say that you're unlikely to get good answers on those sites, since SO has so many experts who may have more valuable information to give.  **That's not a coincidence**.  SO tends to have higher quality content, more experts, etc. *specifically because it is restrictive in the questions that it allows*.  By prohibiting questions that have shown, over an extensive history, to cause problems and result in lower quality content, the remaining questions end up being (largely) of great quality, and it creates a site that experts *want* to be active on, as they don't have to deal with a lot of the lower quality questions, the bike sheds, and the arguments/flamewars/ranting/etc. that come along with questions like those you suggested.

Comment: You can ask them on SO chat too.

Comment: I'm not sure this is true. Sure, removing *very* low quality questions definitely helps, but I seriously doubt removing "subjective" or "too broad" questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351733/can-you-write-object-oriented-code-in-c) help. That "too broad" question has a simple, definite, one-sentence answer. Ridiculous. The real reason SO became so popular is because the voting system works pretty well, and the UI isn't utter shit (compare it to the mess of Quora for example). In fact the UI is very good.

Comment: @Timmmm There are lots of sites with voting systems.  SO was emulating *other* sites with its voting system.  Your example of a question that's "not too broad" is one that literally says to read a book, because it takes that whole book to answer that question.  That's the *textbook example* of what it means for a question to be too broad.  The help center literally uses, "would take a whole book to answer the question" as an example of a question that's too broad.  That "answer" doesn't answer the question, it just tells you that an answer exists somewhere else.

Comment: No, the answer is "yes, see this book for details". The question wasn't "tell me every detail of how to do OOP in C" it was "can you do it?" for which the answer is a simple "yes". See? Also I'd be interested to see the sites that SO was emulating. I can't remember any with a similar voting system, and certainly none with a clean, modern, uncluttered UI like SO's.

Comment: @Timmmm And *that* answer isn't even useful.  Just having a "yes" doesn't actually help anyone, and there's no information on which you can judge the accuracy of such an answer, as there isn't even anything supporting such a statement.  It's just not of any value.  That's why yes/no questions tend to not actually generate useful answers.  If someone posted an answer just saying, "yes" and nothing else, would *you* be satisfied with that answer if you asked the question (not knowing the answer when you asked it)?

Comment: @Timmmm As for where SO was taking it's voting system from, the founders specifically referenced sites like Reddit and Slashdot as examples that they were following with their voting system, although *lots* of other sites had been emulating those (and other) sites' by having a voting system.

Comment: It is clearly useful - just look at the number of votes. And Reddit and Slashdot aren't for programming questions so how exactly would they have competed with SO?

Comment: @Timmmm This is a good example of problems with the voting system where you cannot equate votes to usefulness, for the same reason that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/) isn't actually one of the most useful questions on the site, despite having a vote score that would lead you to believe as much.  Consider that around a tenth of a percent of the people that read that post indicated that they thought it was useful, and that that answer is shown above all others, regardless of its score, due to being accepted, and SEO's positive feedback loops.

Comment: @Timmmm As for Reddit and Shalshdot, they don't exist *exclusively* for programming questions, and yet lots of programmers asked lots of technical questions on those sites, and there were certain places on those sites specifically for such question.  There were also other dedicated Q/A sites, like SO, that emulated voting behaviors from sites like those.  Again, *the founders of SO* were specifically talking about how common voting was on their competitors when they created the site.  It wasn't their innovation; it was them taking something from others that they thought was useful.

Comment: "lots of programmers asked lots of technical questions on those sites" - I don't think that is true. Before SO the first port of call for programming questions would have been *forums*, including general ones like CodeGuru and specific forums for the technology you are using (e.g. forum.jquery.com). Slashdot literally never had "How do I do X?" questions on its front page. Proggit I'll grant you, and that [was cited](https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/), but along with Experts Exchange!!

Comment: @Timmmm I have never used Slashdot, so I couldn't comment further on it.  I know Reddit certainly has places for programming questions that people ask.  You're right that forums were also another one of SO's competitors, forums like, say, the MSDN forum, which *had voting on posts*, but yes, also competitors that didn't have voting.  The point is simply that voting wasn't what made SO unique; the thing that it did that all of those other places *weren't* doing was having strict quality standards on questions and answers, and requiring posts to be useful to more than just the OP.

Answer (score 11):

> I don't think SO should be Wikipedia. I think that if I could ask a question to a group of skilled programmers sitting around a table at lunch, and get interesting, valuable answers, then I don't care whether the question or the answers are 'subjective', I think that question should equally well be fair game for Stack Overflow.

Some questions aren't really answerable questions, they are discussions.

Stack Exchange is a Q/A network, not a discussion board.

---

Interestingly, a Wikipedia type site seems to me the exact format you are wanting - because you can have more discussion of pros/cons to different things which is more applicable to an article than an "answer."

Answer (score 11):

I understand why you and others ask this question.  Sometimes questions with a fair amount of subjectivity *do* receive useful answers, possibly get heavily upvoted, then get closed.

The main goal of SO is that someone can use a search engine to get an answer about a topic, and have a really good chance of getting useful information.  So, why sometimes close questions that have elicited useful information?

To understand that you have to understand the *effort* it takes to make sure answer quality is reasonably high.  Even with the current, pretty strict, guidelines (which *do* sometimes rule out useful content) a *lot* of people volunteer (a very few get paid) what is collectively an enormous amount of time just trying to maintain the current standards - and are struggling to even do that (the backlog in the review queues is enormous).

So, like many matters in programming, you have to drop the ideal (in which hordes of knowledgeable and benevolent moderators and users spend the time needed to curate any number of subjective questions, deal with the many people who are upset that their question has been rejected while a similar one has not (because, you know, that's pretty much inherent in the whole subjective thing), and generally spend the large amounts of time needed to *make* things ideal) in favor of the possible (in which smaller hordes of overall surprisingly knowledgeable users and moderators spend an enormous amount of time curating the site but often come up with heuristics to save enough time to make completing the job possible).

Some of the time-saving heuristics include closing categories of questions that historically have taken up large amounts of curator's time and produced a disappointing quantity and quality of good content.  I agree with you that some good content is lost, and certain categories of very useful content are nearly absent from SO.  I think after a little time on the site this problem is readily apparent.

What is less readily apparent is how very hard it is to have that content without burying it under content of far lower quality.  I would love to see some method of solving that.  I'd complain too - it seems a shame that certain things are missing - but, unfortunately, I don't have a feasible solution that scales to the level of this site and uses the resources available.  I don't think anyone has figured that out.

Comment: The backlog of the close vote queue is high.  The other queues generally sit around zero...

Comment: You said: "The main goal of SO is that someone can use a search engine to get an answer about a topic, and have a really good chance of getting useful information." I would say that an encyclopedia is a better format for persistent, high quality information. If you want people to do research to get their questions answered, make them do research. If the documentation of a language or tool does not address something, you just have to experiment. There is no Q&A in a library. The Q&A format is where you went wrong. A new question every 10 seconds? Wow. I would never have signed up for that.

Comment: Finally, an answer that lets me empathize with the anti-subjectives instead of thinking they hate fun.

Answer (score 8):

Edit 5/16/2019:

I've realized this really just **comes down to a misapplication of the [original Atwood article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)**. People applying it not recognizing how the nuances and abstract nature of programming make it a different case than cameras and graphics cards.  I'm not saying Jeff was wrong.  I'm saying the people that are taking an article written in the context of "superuser.com" with all hardware examples, are doing a disservice to stackoverflow.com by insisting programming components are the same thing.

This is a misapplication for a number of reasons:

**There's nothing abstract in the camera example**

If somebody asked "I need to capture a highly accurate image of a scene in a very low amount of time, would anybody balk if somebody said you need a need a "Kodak"?  And before you say yeah, but that's a brand name, [what if it's 1889?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_camera#Kodak_and_the_birth_of_film)  There's a time lag between when something goes from abstract to common concept.  Just because we can take for granted that everybody knows what generalized component concept of "camera", does not mean we have the same thing in programming yet.

**He asks a *specific* question about cameras.  But in the case of programming libraries, we're either asking a general question, or we are asking a specific question with context.**

For example, when somebody asks "What component can I use to dynamically create a PDF file?", they are really saying "How do I write a Excel document from this data I have?". The fact that they had the notion that the answer is likely an existing library and phrased it as "what component" does NOT make it a shopping question, but instead simply shows a very basic understanding of programming.

**This misapplication is dated**

In an age of EVERYTHING being modular in a NuGet or npm, "component" as universal as an "if" statement, even what would once have been considered "native" libraries.

**Rewriting "component" questions does not change the answers"

In Atwood's example of "which camera should I buy for low light photography", his rewrite of the question "which features should i look for for low light photography" will result in DIFFERENT answers.

However, in the case for programming components, if somebody says "How do I write data to an Excel file?", they are still likely to get the same references to components.  So the guidance here should be to simply suggesting a rephrase of the question rather than closing it.

**Asking what we should learn is EXTREMELY subjective, especially in programing**

Jeff states: "Thus, when it comes to shopping questions, don’t ask us what you should buy — ask us what you need to learn to tell what you should buy"

I think this ok when a concept is well established.  Cameras might be a good example.  A question like ASP.NET vs. JSP is well established as dynamic web technologies. But what exactly is the conversion for most component questions?  In the case of writing an Excel file, do I really need to learn the openXml standard?  In the case of a reading a web response, do I really need to learn the whole TCP/IP protocol?

**Dated answers are handled by the voting mechanism**
Atwood states that specific answers are only valid for a year.  This decidedly NOT true for many component answers.  Even if it was, the voting mechanism will take care of that for us, buy letting old answers sink over time.

**Follow up questions don't really apply**
Jeff gives the following questions that would need to be asked in a true shopping question, but I can answer them all right now for all component questions.  As further evidence, I challenge anybody to find any of these questions in the comments on ANY question on Stack Overflow:

```
What is your budget?
```

First off, have you really worked with so many of these components that you can give me multiple answers?  In any case, I'll take the cheapest one.

```
Where do you live?
```

Cyberspace.

```
What are your preferences?
```

See tags.

```
Which alternatives will you consider?
```

Working code.

```
When do you want to buy?
```

Yesterday, I'm already behind deadline.

----End Edit---

My original answer:

My discussion on this was closed ([Too many closed questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192019/230493)) referring me here to this question.

This is not an answer, but further support for the asker:

It would seem that if there is even the possibility of the question being subjective, it is closed.  These days there must be a dozen ways to code something, yet those questions are allowed to stand.  Yet the instant somebody asks a "what is a library that will do 'X' it is closed.  The irony is that these questions, even in their closed and decaying state, are often the most valuable to me.  Sometimes I'll test three or four third party components before I commit to one.  This is a time consuming process that I would gladly augment with the vote-validated answers that others might have.

Examples include:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744966/any-open-source-c-sharp-ocr-library
- [How do I create an Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file in C# without installing Microsoft Office?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp/2603625#2603625)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408212/best-net-blog-engine
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361271/best-free-controls-for-net/361331#361331

I'll concede that the last one is too general but I left it on there because even if it was free control that does 'X' it still would have been closed.

If these questions cannot be asked on Stack Overflow proper, which subsite should be considered (keeping in mind that the other sides hardly get anywhere close to the SERP rankings that Stack Overflow gets).

Does the asker need to explicitly ask the ["subjective" guidance questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) to avoid getting closed?:

- Please explain “why” and “how”
- Please elaborate
- Please only share items that you have personal experience with.
- Please post any data you have relating to your experience

Isn't that a mess?  Shouldn't we be able to rely on the answerers to follow the guidelines instead and if they violate them make effective use of the down vote button beyond simply being wrong?  Why does all the burdon fall on the asker when it's the answerers that should know the rules and how they can best serve the asker without turning them away?

Are these questions even subjective?  It is a fact if a component meets a need.  "Best" is subjective, but isn't that inherent anyway?  Is anybody going to list the item they've already discarded for themselves?  Are we really going to let a single adjective decide a questions fate?  Isn't this easily cleaned up with comments?

I understand we're trying to avoid the wild west of a forum, but we're not debating politics here.  Many of these questions could be answered with "here's what I did and here's why".  We could restrict answers to things that are pulled directly from the examples on MSDN, but why exactly do we want to do that?

What is the guiding principle here?  If we want to help programmers save time and create better software, then things that stop them from getting to page 17 on Bing should be included.

EDIT:

For those that chose to dismiss my examples as "shopping" questions please explain the difference between asking "How do I create an excel file from .net" (which there are dozens of un-closed examples of and "What is the best component for creating an excel file".  Doesn't one question simply acknowledge that the best candidate for an answer is likely going to be a component?

If there is no place for subjectivity on Stack Overflow, what is the point of the voting mechanism?

Comment: `Why does all the burdon fall on the asker when it's the answerers that should know the rules...?`  Because the asker should know the rules as well?  Because the question helps shape the answers?  Because a bad question pretty much (but not always, I'll concede) guarantees bad answers?

Comment: @LBT - I'm not suggesting that the asker shouldn't follow the rules.  I'm suggesting that in the context of the set of solicitations that automatically qualifies a question as a valid subjective question, that answerers are likely the more experienced of the two and should know to include the responses to those solicitations without explicitly been asked.

Comment: @b_levitt Yes, this is just common sense; but people don't like using [or have any] common sense these days. So we have to think for them.

Comment: We've already seen others argue the, "Everything is modular now, so we have to allow recommendations" angle.  It doesn't change anything about why we disallow them.

Comment: They are allowed, only if proper specification is provided in the question such that an answer can be provided with supporting evidence as to why said thing is the way to go. "because it's popular" or "because it's clean" isn't useful reasoning.

Comment: @fbueckert - and you didn't comment on one of the other FIVE reasons because...?  Can you point me to an article listing those reasons?  I was originally directed to the above mentioned Atwood article.

Comment: The last M.SO post arguing this stance is here, I believe; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369946/1197934  I see no reason to re-iterate those arguments.  None of your other arguments are persuasive enough to overcome the core point, and some are borderline dismissive of dissent.  I suppose I'm basically dismissing your dissent, so as my response go, that one's pretty weak.  Second attempt: the core argument just feels like a misunderstanding of why they're off-topic.

Comment: And throughout all of this, there's nothing stopping someone from recommending a library as an *answer*; good answers can do that, and would also explain how to use the library to solve the problem.  It's questions *asking* for recommendations that are closed for their problematic aspects.

Comment: It's all the same arguments.  But what is the basis.  Where does it say that stackoverflow.com does not allow these questions to begin with?  All I know of is the Atwood article.  And frankly i've already agreed that the questions can be reworded to fit more of a technical question format without eluding to a component (even if it's obvious), it's why do they have to be closed, instead of simply asked to be rewritten?

Comment: It's in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  It needs to be closed because editing of that nature changes the intent, which only the asker can do.

Comment: who said the asker can't edit it?

Comment: They can.  But you vote on a post as it is *right now*.  Not what you think it can turn into.

Comment: You're argument is entirely circular...you are using the very vote category we would like to reduce or eliminate as the reason you can't eliminate it.  DON'T vote...ask the user the reword the question instead.

Comment: How you vote is up to you. For most curators, there's much less confidence that users will attempt to fix their question, and have no time to guide them to do so. So they, and I, vote right away, and move on.

Answer (score 8):

> Even if they do become a bit of a discussion

Well, that's the crux of the matter, right?

We find **discussion** to detract from the purpose of the site - to be a repository of **questions and answers**.

Popularity and usefulness don't come into that equation.

Comment: so you're saying you don't care how useful the questions and answers are?  Isn't that the whole point of the site?  I for one only come here because I find it useful, not because I enjoy long discussions or debates.

Comment: @MattDarwin A discussion or debate is not an answer though. We want questions with answers.

Comment: @MattDarwin Stack overflow optimises for total usefulness. If a rule makes the site more useful for you but less useful for 100 other people that is optimised against. This is of course accross all questions; if a rule stops 1 useful question and 99 unhelpful ones then it is a good rule

Comment: No. The point is to have a repository of questions and answers. Not a repository of useful debate or discussion. We focus on our mission, @MattDarwin

Answer (score 3):

**Design questions call for judgement**

Very often the kinds of questions of the "how do you design X?" variety call for judgement.  Often, that judgement comes with experience.  Providing a satisfactory answer (possibly among many such answers) usually requires the kind of background that comes from having solved a similar design problem in the past, and seeing the aftermath.

There are two wrinkles in this.

First, there can be many satisfactory answers to a design question.  Choosing among those answers can, in fact, be subjective.  But that doesn't mean that the satisfactory answers, as a group, don't add value.  It also doesn't mean that the question itself is subjective to the point of lacking merit.

Second, the asker usually doesn't recognize their case as belonging to a given design pattern.  The only people who see the pattern are those who are acquainted with one or more of the satisfactory answers.  So the question usually lacks the definition that will make it obviously belonging to a pattern.

The result is that design questions are often marked as subjective and closed prematurely.  Those of us who see a pattern in the question need to respond, even if there are votes to close in progress.  I'm not saying this applies to all questions with votes to close.  Just the ones where there is a non obvious pattern at play.

Answer (score 1):

Some of these questions are very old. Over time, Stack Overflow has become more strict on what is allowed.

And these strict rules are there for a reason. There are enough places where people talk about which tool is "the best". Stack Exchange sites aim at giving definite, objective answers.

Questions also need to show prior effort. This prevents the site from being overrun by "help vampires".
But also, when I have a problem and look on most other sites, I see a list of things that I've already tried myself. When I look on Stack Overflow, I find someone else who has also tried these things - and failed. Then (hopefully) an answer follows that shows a new insight, that I have *not* yet tried myself.

So, even though there may be informative things in the answers, questions asking for "the best product" or questions that show zero effort should be closed. It may seem harsh, but it is necessary if we want to keep a high signal-to-noise ratio.

Answer (score 1):

SO has some standards for questions to be welcomed... the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) has detailed information about what you can ask in here and what you cannot ask.

- [JPA Implementations - Which one is the best to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576659/jpa-implementations-which-one-is-the-best-to-use): SO expects questions to be *answerable*. That question is opinion based and also the answer can change according to your requirements. This is not a discussion site, you can ask your questions and get direct answers.

  Also probably it will not offer much as a future reference since
  requirements differ and choices change too. If some application is
  the best choice at present, that does not mean it will be the best in 3
  years time.
- [How to read a large text file line by line in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-in-java): SO is not a place where you can make other people do your job. You must try and search before you ask something in here. You must have some specific problem to be solved, not a whole concept to be written for you.

  Closing an answered question is necessary because if it is not closed, then it will encourage people keep doing the same thing. If SO do not close an answered question which do not fit its format, then people keep asking them since they will think "No problem, we got our answers".
- [Are weekly status meetings necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080499/are-weekly-status-meetings-necessary): SO is for programming questions. [SX has many sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for many Q&A formatted questions and this is not the right place. Visit [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) for such questions.

And one more thing, this is a community moderated site. If there are no strict lines for moderating, then everything will be a mess. There are thousands of people in here who can access moderator tools and there must be guidelines for them to follow.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer from reading many of the replies here is that the current infrastructure wasn't made to accommodate subjective discussions.  The best way SO could reign in the "subjective vigilantes" is to provide infrastructure to support subjective exchanges.  In this way the [subjective and objective questions could be dealt with differently](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6413/88091).

Answer (score 1):

I personally sort of agree with you, and I searched this question up before I was going to ask it myself. To me it seems like some questions are unnecessarily closed for the sake of being stubborn about enforcing the rules, because I think they can be very useful questions, and others undoubtedly believe this too. For example, what if I wanted to ask "What is a good Java dictionary library?" and I couldn't find the answer to this elsewhere? Should I use a different site just to ask this? I know there won't be as many responses on different sites and they won't be as "good," so I'm naturally inclined to ask them on Stack Overflow. But don't interpret this the wrong way, I'm new to Stack Exchange and these are only the truthful thoughts from a naive perspective, and I'm sure there are reasons for closing subjective responses.

Comment: I'm sorry but your question fails on more than one point. Besides being subjective, it's also a list question, a poll, and one that's likely to be rendered obsolete over time. There are likely several options for books on this. If you really need this, find a chat room and ask there. You'll likely get some good recommendations. SE does try go cover a lot of ground but really subjective content doesn't really fit our format. There's nothing wrong with your question in general but the SE Q&A format isn't optimized for this.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2017, there's a few sites, both established and in beta where answers *are* somewhat subjective, and have covered subject material one might consider a little too subjective on older sites. In a sense, the trick's really to propose, and build up sites that can handle subjective topics well, rather than try to shoehorn a traditional forum structure of "anything goes"

The advantage of the 'traditional' Q&A site has been that the format, for most part has been designed to minimise noise. Quite a few original design decisions, were focused around that, and site norms have evolved over time - we have Product Recommendation sites (for [software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) and [hardware](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com)) - which are arguably subjective, that probably wouldn't have existed before.

We also have fairly dedicated sites like workplace and IPS that cover subjects that by nature that are subjective.

I find in many cases, that these sites often have fundamentally different dynamics from more traditional Q&A sites. There's a little more drama, and a few issues we'd never face.

Many of the sites often need to find their feet as far as scope goes - SR had the "You're doing it all wrong" [post](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/youre-doing-it-all-wrong) for example. And while I find "what's the best tool" to do "bar" makes for a terrible question - there's little loss when [you're getting answers that include the process and not just the tools](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) on more traditional, purely non subjective sites.

In both cases - there's never been a total ban on subjective posts- [there's been rules of the road for these since 2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), and many of these work brilliantly even on sites which are purely subjective.

Comment: Could you add a link to your reference to "Product Recommendation sites"?  Thanks.

Comment: per my observations Workplace (and to lesser extent IPS since it's still actively evolving) look fairly close to "classical" Q&A, with sufficiently strong and objective quality norms. As for perception of these sites being more dramatic this seems to be effect of (usually artificial) popularity caused by advertising in the hot list. I think same "dramatic" effects would be observed even on canonical Stack Overflow if system wouldn't [push their questions out of HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250154/165773) - bursts of upvotes and answers, heated debates in comments etc etc...

Comment: ...in fact that's just what I usually observe in Stack Overflow questions that get organically popular to the extent sufficient to overcome system protection keeping these out of HNQ - this just happens too rarely to make an impression similar to one made by Workplace / IPS

Answer (score -9):

Stack Exchange is by now a failing product that doesn't serve the needs of those asking questions, but rather a handful of 20k+ rep members gaming the system to feed their own egos. It's like Facebook and the toxic social media only 10x worse.

I've been calling on the site to fix itself for years and only received downvotes, closes/on-holds in exchange.

The best way to "encourage" Stack Overflow to change is to create an alternative, preferably one where there are no downvotes and moderators are held to account for every single mistake.

Comment: Considering SO  in many ways was a reaction to perceived flaws with another Q&A ... Maybe you might be on to something. That said - there's been a few attempts that haven't worked. Maybe you might have better luck.

Comment: I've been looking for other Q&A sites (specifically something that doesn't have a downvote button and is focused on helping people instead of throwing bureaucratic rules intheir way. Can you recommend one? (Found a list at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Q%26A_sites )

Comment: Nope. I like it here.

Comment: Re *"that doesn't serve the needs of those asking questions"*: What percentage of those ask very simple questions that are duplicates?

Comment: You can probably find a site where the Eternal September event hasn't happen yet, and it will be great. What will you do when that happens and the regulars get very tired of answering the same questions over and over again? Move to the next site?

Comment: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) works surprisingly well for a site that [allows](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-a-wooden-ball-the-size-of-Texas-fell-into-the-ocean/answer/Dave-Consiglio) [everything](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-you-instantaneously-moved-Uranus-so-that-it-was-touching-Earth) [that ends with a "?"](https://www.quora.com/What-would-happen-if-99-of-the-earths-crust-became-Uranium-235/answer/Dave-Consiglio), but you can't really post code, the question is limited to 250 characters, and it doesn't really have downvotes for questions (only technically).

Comment: Quora also has a moronic "real name" policy and it suffered an embarrassing hack 1-2 years ago that leaked info from massive numbers of users. I'm not using them until they abolish the "real name" policy. Then again, Quora was founded by a bunch of ex-Facebook engineers, so no surprises they demand everyone's personal information and have no qualms about incompetently leaking.