# Is there history of the StackOverflow/StackExchange -sites available somewhere?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-history

Found some info in Wikipedia and some info in blog, but is there longer (full) story available somewhere?

Comment: [Start here, at the bottom](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/page/31/). ;)

Comment: FWIW, Programmers.SE history is [laid out here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773). As for Stack Overflow, besides links provided at [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow), it is probably worth studying [The Unproven Path](http://www.inc.com/magazine/20081101/how-hard-could-it-be-the-unproven-path.html) by Joel Spolsky _"...one day this guy named Jeff Atwood called me up..."_