# Question about differences between React and Angular.js deleted without explanation

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, deleted-questions, list-questions

When Facebook React.js came out, I was curious to know how it was different from AngularJS and posted a question only to have it "closed as not constructive". I found out that my question has now been deleted. This is a very non-transparent system of moderation that I really think needs to be better managed.

When I found out the question was closed, I reworded it to ask specifically about the technical differences between the two frameworks. Others in the community also modified the question to be as objective as possible.

Still, there was no response from the users who voted to close as to why it was still in violation. More months passed and it resulted in the question being deleted, also with no explanation. I strongly believe that this community should be founded on transparency, rather than make it appear that the few who are "credible" should be able to make decisions without explanation.

SO Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847273/differences-between-facebook-react-and-angular-js

[image: The question worded before it was deleted. No feedback was given since the initial post]

[image: The violation]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions. Also see this [faq question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/172661)

Comment: I was hopeful that this kind of question might be accepted on the new Software Recommendations site, but it appears they're not. [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-tool-x-versus-tool-y-a-fair-question)

Comment: It should not have been deleted with that many upvotes.  It should have been allowed to get some good answers and then closed.  You should leave a link here, so that if anyone wants to they can cast an undelete vote.

Comment: @BilltheLizard this restriction sounds promising, I think having it greatly increases chances for new site to survive and avoid troubles like those that caused [NPR fiasco](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: @BilltheLizard ...do you by chance know if they consider a rule similar to famous Skeptics.SE _back it up_?

Comment: @gnat I haven't spent any time looking at their meta site (aside from finding the above linked question), so I don't know if they have a similar rule.

Answer (score 9):

You're asking for a list of differences between two frameworks, which, if it exists at all, should be found in the documentation for those frameworks. The close reason already explains why the question is off-topic on Stack Overflow, and editing failed to make it on-topic.  It's been several months, the question is not going to be reopened and answered, and it's a waste to have it show up in search results.  I think it was rightly deleted.

Comment: I don't think the list of differences is always found in the documentation of the frameworks. That puts too much responsibility on the framework documenters. This is why we have independent sites like SO to answer these questions. We can "expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise" if we focus the what the question asks to give strictly factual data. Furthermore, based on that, the question was revised and no further feedback was given. The reason why they deleted it seems to make sense thought. I just wish they would have explained that when the question was deleted.

Comment: The question might have been edited, but the whole premise was the same, so nobody thought it warranted changing the votes @jon

Comment: "should be found in the documentation for those frameworks" in that case most questions on Stack would have to be deleted if the person asking the question should merely read the documentation.

Comment: @captDaylight If that was the only reason the question was closed and deleted, you might have a point.

Comment: @BilltheLizard then why use it as part of your argument?

Comment: @captDaylight Why not? It's only part of the argument, not the whole thing. It doesn't apply to all questions, only some.