# Appropriate forum for software critique?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I understand and respect why StackOverflow will close or even remove some questions that are too subjective or not answerable with concrete facts and citations. This is a good thing, as it improves the richness of actual knowledge here and discourages flame wars and trolling.

My question is, is there a StackXXX variant focused on software critique? That is, entirely subjective discussions on the relative merits of this language or that tech stack, but with a bias towards informed debate as opposed to religious/flame war stuff?

As I explore new (to me) technology, I will sometimes hit Google to dig up a lot of opinions/discussions about that technology, in part to sanity check my naive reactions (e.g. maybe the initial learning curve is bumpy but it truly is worth the effort to grok it), and in part to discover the reasons a technology is the way it is. E.g. there was a conscious philosophy to trade off DRY for explicit; it follows the widely familiar pattern of the older Foo platform; it's like that "for historical reasons"... This can really matter to a developer as sometimes that smell your smelling is something your gut should trust, whereas sometimes the more knowledgeable perspective can underscore why tech X is worth a deeper look. Case in point, way back, it took me 3 subsequent attempts of rainy Sunday afternoons to get past the whitespace-as-semantics aspect of Python and realize it was not (SO NOT) as it appeared, a silly little toy language for doing silly little scripty things (though Python also excels at this :)

I haven't used it a lot and it may be new enough to not know how it may be used, but Quora.com is interesting for broader topics than just software and technology. I wonder if there is something more like StackOverflow for the philosophical and critical stuff.

Comment: @gnat - It seems to me I'm asking a very distinct question. I'm not suggesting or asking that SO change in any way; I'm asking where there may be a similar forum for the more subjective discussions.

Comment: have you read the [top answer there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)? **"We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."**

Comment: I think you're looking for [Slant](http://slant.co/).

Comment: I read the linked question and answers. Knowing how this failed as a past experiment clarifies a lot, thanks for linking it. Sigh, I guess this is why we can't have nice things. Slant may evolve into something but seems much shallower than SO at the moment. Ditto Quora.