# Replace "Programming Questions" close reason with "Migrate to Meta Stack Overflow"

Tags: feature-request, migration, close-reasons, meta

Since the division of Meta's into Meta Stack Exchange and Meta Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow has a real meta. The previous Meta was moved to here but it still has some legacy functionalities which would not serve as good as it was before. An example of this is: **Close » Off-Topic » Programming questions are off topic**.

Basic reasons of this request are:

1. Since the url had switched from *meta.stackoverflow.com* to *meta.stackexchange.com* it would be less likely people will post programming questions to here.
2. Questions are migrating from one meta to other, but it would be fine if we can help Mods in the process. I do not have Vote to Close privilege but at least in the Flag menu, there is no flag for migration option. And there are [questions available for Migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes)

*Flag reason screen looks as below*

[image]

So, that close/flag reason slot may be replaced with *Migrate to Meta Stack Overflow*.

Comment: I agree that we should remove that close reason and it's likely to be unnecessary now. I don't see us replacing it with a migration path, though. I don't anticipate needing to migrate so many new questions (beyond the initial migrations that are happening as part of the split) that a user-driven path is going to be helpful.

Comment: @Anna Lear: It took approximately [2 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229950/i-need-add-checksum-in-java-clinet-server) for this site to receive its first programming question from a user who was question-banned on SO. It would be cool if you guys monitored this to see if the split really does significantly reduce the amount of programming questions being posted where they don't belong.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Yeah, that's a good idea. We can check for the # of questions closed as programming-related (hah).

Comment: Why would a programming question be migrated to *Meta* Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Matthew only the **space** is being suggested to be reused. I.e get rid of one and put in an *entirely new* reason

Comment: possible duplicate of [New Custom Close Reason: Specific Only To A Certain Site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230130/new-custom-close-reason-specific-only-to-a-certain-site)