# New Custom Close Reason: Specific Only To A Certain Site

Tags: discussion, meta, custom-close-reasons

Part of the promise we made when we [split MSE away from MSO](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/) is that users of MSE would keep *most* of their reputation and privileges. In order to make sure this happens, we must curtail migration of questions that are Stack Overflow specific to an essential minimum - reputation is lost on migrated post regardless of score and age.

As planned, we migrated a little over 250 questions back to MSO; these were primarily tag related discussions that had no resolution, along with small helpings of support and SO specific feature requests. While there are some gems left to mine, we're not going to be sending more back over in bulk, and we're going to be *very* reluctant to migrate anything that would cause users to lose privileges - bucketing alone isn't worth the aggravation that would cause them.

To this, we're making some changes to the custom close reasons here on MSE. The following just went live:

> This question **pertains only to a specific site** in the Stack Exchange
> Network. Questions on Meta Stack Exchange should pertain to our
> network or software that drives it as a whole, within the guidelines
> defined in [the help
> center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You should ask
> this question on the meta site where your concern originated.

... which replaces the close reason indicating that programming questions are off-topic. Yes, we've seen a few programming questions come in, but the folks that have been asking them would *clearly* not benefit from the guidance that the reason offers. Simply close those as you would anything else that isn't on-topic as defined in the help center.

You can use this new close reason for anything that should just be asked on a child meta site - stuff that doesn't warrant discussion on the senate floor. This might come in the form of:

- *User 1234 was rude to me on Pets*
- *This question on Physics should not have been closed*
- *Those moderators on Programmers don't delete enough questions*

Rather than migrate *all* of the extremely Stack Overflow specific content, for the sake of everyone keeping privileges, it's better to simply close it. That which retains value can just stay, that which has lost all relevancy can simply be deleted over time (and not cause anyone to lose a 1k chunk of rep in an hour).

*If* you find a question that is still relevant, unresolved and still actionable by the folks on MSO - feel free to flag it, just know that we might not take the requested action.

[faq](/questions/tagged/faq) questions should just be left alone at this point, as it's a massive collection and tightly linked together. A *lot* of that content relates to the network at large, editing is probably going to be preferable to closing or migrating in most cases. There's still quite a bit of cleanup work to be done post-split, but we expected as much.

This gives you something you can do with stuff that really isn't on-topic here any longer, as well as new questions that come in which are really a matter that specific communities should be discussing.

Comment: Should "on the meta site where your concern originated" be "on the meta of the site where your concern originated"? Maybe does not flow as easily, but is more precise.

Comment: What about "escalation" type questions.  A user asks a question on their meta, doesn't feel like he gets a fair response, is asking on MSE still on-topic even though it only pertains to a specific site?

Comment: @psubsee2003 The team *should* be reviewing the child metas as a matter of course - so anything site specific can be escalated by bumping and flagging in place. Even if it's important, if it's specific to one site it should remain on that site's meta.

Comment: If it's migrated _from_ a child meta site, there's a pretty good chance that others would see why. Escalation, as in you went to _your_ meta but didn't get what you think you were due, is generally going to be through [contacting us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) anyway. Mods _can_ send stuff here, and generally only did so to MSO when it was a clear network issue, I don't expect that to change post-split.

Comment: @TimPost is there a good reason it's not set up so we can just migrate these where they should go instead of a custom close reason?

Comment: @waxeagle Migration dialog would need some amount of developer work to accommodate 100+ meta sites.

Comment: @HowAboutaNiceBigCupof I'm picturing something closer to the current mod migrate interface, where you just type where you want it to go, filtered for meta only.

Comment: Is "pertains" a good word to use in a system message for people who don't have English as a first language?

Comment: So this essentially means that every closed question here is going to need to be duplicated on mSO since questions there cannot be closed as duplicates of mSE content.

Comment: Why not just tear off the bandaid? Have a community bulletin encourage users to strip Stack Overflow tags from Meta Stack Exchange posts *where relevant* for a few days. Then, once only Stack Overflow relevant tags are left, migrate the entire set back to Meta Stack Overflow. The end result of this whole ordeal has left Meta Stack Overflow looking bleak. It only has 800 posts at the moment. If no more posts are migrated its relevance will fade as more and more "duplicate" questions are asked there and then pointed here - especially if the Stack Overflow tag remains here.

Comment: I don't understand that bit about privileges. Privileges on MSO have been completely reset since MSO rep is now based on SO history rather than MSO history. MSE is new, so there is no legacy to align with.

Comment: "users of MSE would keep most of their reputation and privileges. In order to make sure this happens, we must curtail migration of questions that are Stack Overflow specific to an essential minimum" -- that does not make sense to me. Why should rep earned with SO-specific content be kept on MSE rather than MSO? (Also, if you used network rep for MSE all those people would probably end up with at least as much privileges on MSE as before.)

Answer (score 11):

Can you make part of the reason bold, so that it fits in with the other reasons and is more scannable? Something like this would be awesome:

> This question **pertains only to a specific site** in the Stack Exchange Network. Questions on Meta Stack Exchange should pertain to our network or software that drives it as a whole, within the guidelines defined in the help center. You should ask this question on the meta site where your concern originated.

Comment: Needz moar bold, agreed. Done.