# Should we close old questions in Meta.SE that pertain only to StackOverflow?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close, meta, mso-mse-split

We are having a [custom close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230130/new-custom-close-reason-specific-only-to-a-certain-site) for off-topic that if a question pertains to a specific site.

It's ok for new questions, since we have a separate meta site for StackOverflow now. But, we have a lot of questions about [StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) in this site. Especially, we have many questions regarding [burninate requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request+stackoverflow), [retag requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag-request+stackoverflow), [tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms+stackoverflow) specific to StackOverflow site.

And we also have many discussions about [specific answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-answer) and [specific questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-question+stackoverflow) of StackOverflow.

Should we close all those questions as off-topic?

As I'm one of the close vote reviewer, I need to know this answer for reviewing.

Comment: According to the blog, these should be getting migrated to the SO meta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the question is clearly about Stack Overflow or Meta.SO then yes, by definition you should vote to close. That doesn't mean the question is gone or anything, it just means it is off topic for this site.

If it only refers to Meta.SO or SO in passing and it can easily be edited to refer to either all sites or Meta.SE specifically then it should be edited rather than closed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you're are correct, these should be closed on MSE. According to a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014/228903#comment753455_229487) posted by Shog9♦ on Apr 14, "**they should probably just be deleted**".

Old burninate requests for Stack Overflow tags just add clutter to MSE.