# Suggestions website for helping purchase products?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

Is there a stackexchange site, or subsection on each site, dedicated to people who need to purchase something, but don't know the best option for their requirements?

I'm thinking of "I want to do a task using a cheap computer, requires living outside so must be waterproof and cannot be bigger than a lunchbox, looking for suggestions?"

Such a system could be used by people to be shown many options which may fit the requirement, each option being able to be up-voted just like the existing sites on stackexchange.

**Note to downvoters:** Please leave a message as to why. As mentioned in the comments (@Fish Below the ice) such an experiment is already happening with regards to software.

Comment: Related blog post: [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: Many thanks, you have answered my question. It seems such community recommendations are not suitable for SE sites. Which is unfortunate, as the question and answer format along with tags seems to be a very good format/engine for such a task :-(

Comment: @Drew: There is currently an experiment on this at [softwarerecs.se], but as you can see this is for software only.

Comment: @Fish, I wish I could upvote you more than once! Thanks :-) Also, why not leave this as a possible answer?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but... ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: @PatrickHofman But it's *not* a site-recommendation.  It *is* a request for a new site.  Intentionally mis-tagging the question isn't going to change anything.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because new site proposals belong on Area 51.

Comment: @Servy: you are right. I misjudged the question.

Answer (score 2):

For *software only*, you might want to try [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) (currently in open beta). This is an experiment to see if such a recommendation site is viable.

Do note, however, that they're rather stringent about what is an acceptable answer. The [Question Quality Guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336) and [Tim Post's answer about what makes a good question for that site](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/208) are good places to start. And, of course, do read the *Help Center*.