# Would a Discussion Section complement the Q&A section/theme of Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

A few years ago I was annoyed that such a great question/discussion had to be closed as off topic. It was [Good keyboards for programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2254/what-are-good-keyboards-for-programming) and I was annoyed that such a useful topic (to me) would have stale data because new answers can never be added to make it better when new keyboards hit the market.

After a time I realized why this is a bad idea as it breaks the Q/A theme and leads to not that focused threads. (When you want to look up how to do xyzzy you want terse focused answers to maximize productivity.)

However I thought it would make sense for a fork of all the Stack Exchanges to be made to have sort of a sub section that is for discussions. I thought of this thread today [Incorporating fun into system designs](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/76594/incorporating-fun-into-systems-design/76597#76597). There are some great minds on Stack Exchange that could contribute to future ideas and possibly discuss best practices or ways to do things in the future that may benefit from a discussion. In other words, maybe the IP address scheme to handle IoT would arise here if there was a discussion, etc.

In short, would a discussion sub section to each Stack Exchange site complement or deter from the existing format? (I know this is opinion based but this seemed like a good place to ask.)

**-----Edit----**

For example HoloLens Just game out and not the world of virtual reality and Augmented Reality are become more possible. Wouldn't it be great to be able to discuss the possible things you could do with this in a forum with upvotes that people could reference for years to come? Apparently not we would prefer it stay buried in a chat log that is very rough to reference or link someone to an old post.

Or even better, what do hiring managers look for when hiring Cobol programmers or UX designers. 
What better place to ask that and get some great advice. However we would preferred it to be scattered all over the place in chat logs. Chat logs arnt refactored and theres no hey this is a duplicate post or nearly the same editing as with our Q/A format.

Comment: So you're looking for something next to chat?

Comment: Yes like chat but persistent . Kind of like a forum , topics but not 100% focused down a specific question path. Ie what should we consider when y2k hits ...

Comment: Where one wouldn't look back at chat logs and see idea generation, though if it had a similar format it might throw off search results

Comment: [*Kind of like a forum*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum/92110#92110)

Comment: Yes like a forum sub section or side section. Not a robin to batman but like a Steve Kerr To Jordan. It would be a side feature not trying to detract from the focal point which is the focused Q/A dialogue .

Comment: Similar question [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244972/discussion-forums) and follow all dupes and the unfolding drama. Based on that I say we don't want this...

Comment: Can't you just make a chat room on that particular topic? They _are_ rather persistant.

Comment: not really you cant format your posts in the chat to present ideas as well. Also the nature of the chat is rather off the cuff with a culture of steering towards short terse off the cuff type comments that arent really revised or of the quality that stack exchange Q/A is known for. People rarely edit chat posts i would assume.

Comment: updated , does everyone still feel the same way?

Answer (score 3):

We already do.

I can see that you earned the privilege to participiate in chat. Chat is a place where you can talk and even ask other fellow users. Nothing is really off-topic as long you talk about the subject of the chat room, sometimes it's never off-topic unless you go way too far...

For example, MSE's chat room has a lot of off-topic content if posted here in MSE. But not in the chat room. This is a reason chat rooms were created. To let users simply chat with other about stuff not normally allowed in a post or even a comment.

So, ask your question in chat and see what your fellow users have to say. Thus, the answer to your question is:

> Yes, it is called chat.

And yes, there are chatrooms with a specific topic you can only talk about...

Comment: I need to reedit my question when I get home , I am well aware of the chat function this isn't it. I did a very poor job at explaining myself

Comment: still agree after my edit?