# Why do we add status tags to support questions?

Tags: support, tags, meta

A status tag was recently added to [My support question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380867) (more specifically, [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)). And from my current knowledge, status tags (e.g [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro), etc.) are used for [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)s and [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s. So to make sure my question was unusual, I searched for support questions with status tags. My results:

For all the [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions:

- [109 support questions have the status-bydesign tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bsupport%5d%20and%20%5bstatus-bydesign%5d%20and%20-%5bbug%5d%20and%20-%5bfeature-request%5d%20and%20-%5bdiscussion%5d%20and%20is%3aq)
- [8 support questions have the status-review tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsupport%5D+and+%5Bstatus-review%5D+and+-%5Bbug%5D+and+-%5Bfeature-request%5D+and+-%5Bdiscussion%5D+and+is%3Aq)
- [542 support questions have the status-completed tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsupport%5D+and+%5Bstatus-completed%5D+and+-%5Bbug%5D+and+-%5Bfeature-request%5D+and+-%5Bdiscussion%5D+and+is%3Aq)
- [13 support questions have the status-declined tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bsupport%5d%20and%20%5bstatus-declined%5d%20and%20-%5bbug%5d%20and%20-%5bfeature-request%5d%20and%20-%5bdiscussion%5d%20and%20is%3aq)
- [3 support questions have the status-deferred tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsupport%5D+and+%5Bstatus-deferred%5D+and+-%5Bbug%5D+and+-%5Bfeature-request%5D+and+-%5Bdiscussion%5D+and+is%3Aq)
- [34 support questions have the status-norepro tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsupport%5D+and+%5Bstatus-norepro%5D+and+-%5Bbug%5D+and+-%5Bfeature-request%5D+and+-%5Bdiscussion%5D+and+is%3Aq)

In total, there are 700+ support questions with status tags. So, is my knowledge incorrect? Or do moderators like to add status tags to support questions? Or is there a post in the meta that I haven't seen that says that status tags are also added to support questions?

Comment: "*do people like to add status tags to support questions?*" - No. Please note that those tags are red, and see one of the [tags description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-completed/info): "*Red status tags can only be applied by moderators and site developers*". So it's for their control/workflow

Comment: @hkotsubo right. I forgot that the status tags can only be used by moderators

Comment: Looking at the support questions tagged as completed, most of them seem to be requests for tag changes on Stack Overflow (prior to April 2014 this site also served as the per-site meta for Stack Overflow), which were tagged as completed once the tags were changed as requested. These are tagged as discussions and support questions because they're not bug reports or feature requests for the SE system (see the [old tagging instructions at the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/62919/10)).

Comment: Can be funny (?) if [tag:status-review] would be added here.

Comment: There's nothing to review or do tho >_>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TLDR: We also misuse MSE as a ticketing system.

In a sense - both traditionally and currently MSO/MSE has acted almost like a ticketing system, While the mechanisms vary - from folks keeping an eye on meta(s) actively to the status review tag being linked to the actual ticketing system SE uses internally. Where possible we align it with the [roadmap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348642/what-posts-should-be-escalated-to-staff-using-status-review-and-how-do-i-esca) though we sometimes tag posts of broader community interests as well. We also may use these tags, especially on per site meta, to indicate the *mod team* is reviewing something, or the status of a request, depending on mod culture.

The other status tags allows the community visibility over the status of these posts. Ideally staff would update them, but moderators sometimes retag posts that are obviously talking about resolved issues. With a support tag - completed would indicate that the request made in the question was fulfilled in some way, planned meant they were looking at it and so on.

As such the tags reflect that something has been pushed into the company's radar, and what the decision on said matter is.

Comment: This *might* explain the [tag:status-review] added to support questions, however [tag:status-completed] makes no sense. There was no bug to fix or request to implement. It's just confusing, and might be noise. (non relevant detail added to question.)

Comment: well if you look at that tag, the support *request* was fulfilled in some manner. The exact manner would depend on the question? I didn't really want to get into the weeds about it

Comment: Based on that logic, each and every support question that has an answer should have [tag:status-completed] tag. Sorry, but I totally disagree with that logic. That is just not how this tag should be used.

Answer (score 4):

Your question [How is the Sandbox archive off-topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380867/how-is-the-sandbox-archive-off-topic) is tagged [support](/questions/tagged/support), but it's also possible to read it as a bug report. The question "Is this situation normal?" implies that if it's not, it should be (bug)fixed. Hence I decided to tag it as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). It's the shortest way to indicate 'everything is working correctly' and sometimes, that's all future readers want to know. The alternative is having to read the answers, which takes more time. If you're really bothered by it, we can remove it, but I hope this explanation (and JourneymanGeek's) make a bit of sense.

I see now that the [tag info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-bydesign/info) says it should only be used on bugs, but as you discovered, that's just the theory and in practice those guidelines aren't followed.

Comment: "also possible to read it as a bug report." - so just retag as a [tag:bug], and problem solved.

Comment: I'm not sure if that still puts it in some kind of queue for staff (or that only [status-review] does that now), which would be unnecessary.

Comment: As far as I know, the status review tag is what triggers the internal staff queue.

Comment: @Glorfindel: As Shadow said, I think only status-review escalates it to us in some capacity. We do have a staff tool that lets us see bugs reported network-wide (basically a search/filter for `bug -status-*` on all meta sites by default, with additional filtering/sorting options – and it shows which staff have responded to which posts already), but I don't know how often that gets used now that we have a standardized escalation process.