# What's the proper site of Stack Exchange family to discuss a program implementation

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I want to discuss with fellow programmers a program I want to develop.

Specifically: I want to discuss if Ruby is a good choice, if it's a good idea to call the SoX command from within Ruby and parse the result in Ruby, etc.

Is there an appropriate Stack website for this? If so, which one?

Programmer Stack Exchange warns users of not posting these "discussion" questions (We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.)

If Programmer Stack Exchange is the appropriate website, how should I explain the challenges I face and encourage discussion?

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: Quora accepts such questions. Sample: *[Is Ruby a good choice for back-end programming?](https://www.quora.com/Is-Ruby-a-good-choice-for-back-end-programming?share=1)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a question wouldn't be appropriate on any site in the SE network.  The entire platform is *designed* to prevent discussions.