# How can I tailor this question to three separate sites?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, cross-posting, site-crossover

After some interesting discussions it seems my question fits (is **on topic** for) three different SE sites but if I want to post it to each of them (to access **different kinds of experts**) then I need to tailor the question to fit each community.

Frankly I don't see a way to tailor this particular question any better than it is already written without resorting to silly cosmetic changes. The question is - by its nature - very broad, asking about the *state-of-the-art* in an area where I have interest but no expertise. To be able to "fine tune" the question it feels like I would have to already be an expert in three fields, **in which case I would not have any need for Stack Exchange** in the first place.

Once upon a time Stack Exchange had a very few broad topic areas, but now more-and-more subtopics become new SE sites thus creating overlap that is not precise and lending to the need to cross-post in order to reach different experts in ***different but related*** fields.

Still, I could be wrong. I may be too close to the question to see my options. I would welcome any suggestions on how this question could be *meaningfully* tailored to each of the three following sites:

- Computer Graphics: [What is the state-of-the-art on using computers to "clean-up" images?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1880)
- Signal Processing: [What is the state-of-the-art of using signal-processing for "cleaning-up" videos?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28168)
- Video Production: [What is the state-of-the-art on using computers to "clean-up" videos?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17363)

Comment: "The question is -- by its nature -- very broad". This will likely get your question closed. If you narrow the focus of the question you will probably find it easier to tailor it for each site.

Comment: This is a very bad (due to rapid obsolescence) question.

Comment: Why do you *need* to post it in three different places? What makes you think that you won't get a good answer on just one?

Comment: @HDE226868 I started on the assumption that this questions would be best answered in Computer Graphics SE (the *widest* relevant category) but was almost immediately challenged that it was off-topic for CG. The response on that challenge was it is considered on topic after all, but is also on topic in the Video and Signal Processing SE's. While all three of these overlap some, they each have specialization and so logically they would each have experts that would be unique to those fields and so would be aware of answers that other experts might not even know of let alone be current on.

Comment: Consider if you will that we currently have two education related SE sites. Imagine that we had two others as follows: **Pedagogy** and **Androgogy**. All four would be related and overlapping but there are things about teaching kids that do not apply to teaching adults and vice-versa, and there are things about teaching math that do not apply to other topics, and there are things about higher-ed that do not apply to grammar school. So if I asked a question about the **state-of-the-art** for *computer software for helping teachers* which of the 4 forums is best / right ?

Comment: @ChrisF How would you suggest narrowing the question?

Comment: @O.M.Y. Focus on what the scope of each site is. What information do you want that specific to that scope? However, having said that the question is a "bad" question for Stack Exchange anyway. It'll rapidly become out of date and irrelevant.

Comment: My question was : Here is what we see in fiction, where are we in reality? And that is not allowed at Stack Exchange ?

Comment: @gnat: that post is about subjective questions. I am asking for absolutes of the current STATE of the technology, not recommendations or opinions.

Comment: Also, the more I read "The fourth place" post, that is a post to propose creating a whole new feature / forum on SE. *How on Earth is that even close* to a duplicate of a "How can I reword this specific question?" post?

Comment: @ChrisF: One site (CG) is about creating/modifying digital images, one (DSP) is about modifying digital files including images, and the last (VID) is about creating/modifying video images. The question is about modifying digital video images. I am not trying to be obtuse but please help me (per my original post above) on how I can possibly reword this to target it for each of the 3 forums? It seems to me to be impossible to present this question in any more specific way among these three SE sites other than to make cosmetic changes which IMHO are insulting to the readers' intelligence.

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: It looks like you posted the same question on three different sites.  Don't do that.  [Cross-posting on multiple SE sites is not allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/160917), and there are good reasons for that.  It's also not clear what your question is.  The tone of your post makes it sound like an attempt to justify why you really want to post the same question on three sites.  I understand why you might want to, but cross-posting is still not OK.  My advice: ask a narrower question on just one site, see what answers you get, and use that to help you ask a follow-up question.