# Where should I post a question if I want programming-related advice?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I was contemplating about the path I am headed on as a programmer and wanted some advice on it. Where should I post a question asking for advice related to it? About where to learn stuff from and stuff like that.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing we have for career-related activities is [Workplace Stack Exchange](http://workplace.stackexchange.com). But please read their [Help Center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help) and check with their [Meta support site](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com) specifically.

Stack Exchange sites are meant to ask very *specific* questions about an issue you might encounter with a problem you are working on. If you had a very specific problem you encountered in your search, such questions *might* work, but overly broad questions like "where can I learn {X}" are not going to be well received.

Answer (score 0):

You should either gain some rep, get access to chat and ask such questions in a chatroom where they're welcome, or ask anywhere but Stack Overflow and a Stack Exchange website because the nature of questions you seek an answer to is such that it's not matching the standards on any Stack Exchange site.

See [How can I encourage Stack Overflow to rein in the 'subjective' vigilantes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes) and [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff?s=2|1.1209)

Answer (score -1):

Such a question isn't going to be on topic anywhere on the SE network.